# error compiling C program

Tags: c, compilation

I'm trying to write a program that gets two pointers , and a count of bytes, and compares them . for example , if we have p1 and p2 , and our count is 2 , then we'll check the 2 bytes p1[0]+p1[1] and p2[0]+p1[1].

mem_cmp :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int memcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2, int count)

int main()
{
   char p1[5];
   char p2[5];
   int lexValue;

    memcpy(p1, "01Aa", 5);
    memcpy(p2, "01aA", 5);   

   lexValue = memcmp( p1, p2, 5 );
   if( lexValue == 0 )
        printf( "Both are equal" );
   else if( lexValue < 0 )
    printf( "p2 is bigger than p1" );
   else
    printf( "p1 is bigger than p2" );

return 0;
}
```

memcmp:

```
    int memcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2, int count)
{
   char *p1Char;
   char *p2Char;
   if ( count == 0 )
    return 0;
   p1Char = (char *)p1;
   p2Char = (char *)p2;

   if( *p1Char == *p2Char )
       return memcmp( p1Char+1, p2Char+1, count-1 );
   else
   {
       if( *p1Char > *p2Char )
           return 1;     
       else
       return -1;
   }
}
```

when I try to compile I get this :

```
gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic memcmp.c -o memcmp.o
memcmp.c: In function ‘memcmp’:
memcmp.c:11:7: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
memcmp.c:19:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [memcmp.o] Error 1
```

EDIT:
this is the makefile:

```
memcmp :     mem_cmp.o memcmp.o
              gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic mem_cmp.o memcmp.o -o memcmp
mem_cmp.o:   mem_cmp.c
          gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic mem_cmp.c -o mem_cmp.o
memcmp.o:    memcmp.c
          gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic memcmp.c -o memcmp.o
```

and now this is the error log I see:

```
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic mem_cmp.o memcmp.o -o memcmp
mem_cmp.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
mem_cmp.o: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
mem_cmp.o: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
mem_cmp.o:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
mem_cmp.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
mem_cmp.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_fp_hw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
mem_cmp.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
mem_cmp.o:(.dtors+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in mem_cmp.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [memcmp] Error 1
```

EDIT 2:

no I get only tose warnings :

```
mem_cmp.c:11:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
mem_cmp.c:11:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’ [enabled by default]
gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic mem_cmp.o memcmp.o -o memcmp
```

Comment: You need to use the `-c` option if you're compiling to a `.o` file, otherwise it tries to compile to an executable and it needs a `main()` function.

Comment: You need to `#include` the header file that declares `memcpy`. But that header also declares `memcmp`. That's why you need to give your function a different name.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's all good now

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<string.h>` contains the standard function `memcmp()`. So its prototype conflicts with your version of `memcmp()`.

Also, your function prototype is missing a semi-colin `;`.

Rename your function and add semi-colon:

```
int my_memcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2, int count);
```

and

```
int my_memcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2, int count) {
   ...
   ...
}
```

---

When you declare:

```
   char* p1Char, p2Char;
```

only `p1Char` is a pointer; `p2Char` is just a char. You want:

```
   char* p1Char, *p2Char;
```

Also, note you need `<string.h>` since you are using `memcpy()`.

Comment: I have to use the "memcmp(..)" signature for the assignment.
I removed the string.h now it won't have the conflict.

But now it says :
`memcmp.c:9:19: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
`
along with many warnings

Comment: @BinaryVeil You need `char *p1Char, *p2Char;`. Otherwise, `p2Char` is a `char` not `char*`.

Comment: I fixed that. Now it shows me a different error. (I've edited the original post with the new error info).
Thank you

Comment: @BinaryVeil Please don't change the question. How are future readers supposed to understand what this answer fixed if you change the question?

Comment: You are compiling `memcmp.c` without `main()`. You need to use `-c` option to compile to produce an object file and then link it with your main file.

Comment: but it's a function. It doesn't need to have main. no?
I'm confused

Comment: `gcc -c memcmp.c ; gcc -c mem_cmp.c; gcc -o prog memcmp.o mem_cmp.o`

Comment: Now I only have the warnings:
`mem_cmp.c:11:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
mem_cmp.c:11:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’ [enabled by default]
gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic mem_cmp.o memcmp.o -o memcmp
`
What does it mean?

Comment: @BinaryVeil I have already said you need to include <string.h> for memcpy signature.